# how do you minimize a Silverlight full-screen out of browser app?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

How do you minimize a Silverlight out of browser app that is running full screen with no border? I can't find any documentation on this. I know it's possible, because the Flickr Windows 7 app (which is a OOB SL app) can do it (http://www.flickr.com/Windows7).

The Host or Host.Content properties in the Application doesn't appear to have anything available to solve this. Nor do the Page or UserControl classes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

Should work.

Says that it requires it to be done in response to a user action or there's a security error, just like going full screen.